# Make flexbox grow vertical

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am new to flexbox and I have been playing around with it for some time. I have a requirement that the middle layout needs to grow vertically. Here's what I have:

```css
.main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #F7F8FC;
}

.sub-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="flex-row-item left">
    <button>
      <span>Email</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-row-item center">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <button>
        <span>Previous</span>
      </button>
      <div class="sub-text">
        <span>Item Name: THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT IS really really really long</span>
      </div>
      <button>
        <span>Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-row-item right">
    <button>
      <span>Help</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when the text in "sub-text" starts to get longer and longer, current styling makes the flexbox breaks into a new line along with the "Previous", "Next" and "Help" buttons. I do not want that to happen. Instead how can I just grow the "sub-text" vertically with word wrap while expanding the main container height? For example see this : [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgGXQ.jpg)

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap` is what's pushing the content onto the next line. If you remove that the `.sub-container` will grow vertically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `white-space: pre-line`

```
.sub-text{
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

and there is no need for `flex-wrap: wrap`;

working example:

```css
.main-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #F7F8FC;
}

.sub-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-text{
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="flex-row-item left">
    <button>
      <span>Email</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-row-item center">
    <div class="sub-container">
      <button>
        <span>Previous</span>
      </button>
      <div class="sub-text">
        <span>Item Name: THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT IS really really realddddly londdddddddddddddddddddddddddg</span>
      </div>
      <button>
        <span>Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-row-item right">
    <button>
      <span>Help</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Interesting...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using CSS grids. I think this solution is cleaner than flex.

```css
.main-container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #F7F8FC;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <button>
      <span>Email</span>
    </button>
  <button>
        <span>Previous</span>
      </button>
  <span>Item Name: THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT IS really really really long</span>
  <button>
        <span>Next</span>
  </button>
  <button>
      <span>Help</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

[read more on CSS grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: This look elegant. I will read more on it. meanwhile quick question, can we make the text grow horizontally first and then grow vertically. in your example it looks like width is fixed. is it possible?

Comment: grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr minmax(20%, 80%) 1fr 1fr; 

you can try this and set a min and max value for that content. This should work.